# Find the volume in the first octant bounded by parabolic cylinders $z=9−x^2$ and $x=3−y^2$ using double integration?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, multiple-integral

Find the volume in the first octant bounded by parabolic cylinders $z=9−x^2$ and $x=3−y^2$
using double integration?

below is my attached solution for the question kindly check.

[My solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqPOx.jpg)

the answer of the solution is given in text book is $$v = \ (102{\sqrt3})/35 $$

but my answer is $$v = \ (486{\sqrt3})/35 $$

Comment: Welcome  to Math.SE. It will help if you show your attempt and tell us where you are stuck.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: @Shailesh pls refer to i've posted my solution for the question, but the answer for the question as per text book is $$v = \ (102{\sqrt3})/35 $$